# Capybara: Unable to find xpath "/html" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)

Tags: ruby, cucumber, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I have read a lot of articles online and have yet to find a resolution to my problem. I am using Selenium webdriver:

```
    Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
    Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium
    class FirefoxBrowser
      Capybara.register_driver :firefox do |app|
          client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
      client.timeout = 280
          Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox, :http_client => client)
      end
  end
```

Here is the gemfile:

```
gem "rspec"
gem "ZenTest"
gem "cucumber"
gem "selenium-webdriver"
gem "capybara", "~> 2.1.0"
gem "capybara-webkit", "~> 1.0.0"
gem "simplecov", :require =>false, :group => :test
gem "capybara-screenshot"
gem "autotest", "~> 4.4.6"
gem 'json', '~> 1.7.7'
gem "rack-test", require: "rack/test"
gem "poltergeist"
```

I am running some ruby code using capybara similar to the following:

visit 'https://username:password@website.com/other_params'

this call will return an XML with information regarding whatever call i made. 
from there, i check to see if the page has what im looking for:

page.should have_content("content")

Unable to find xpath "/html" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)

This worked before we upgraded to capybara 2.1.0

Now that we have upgraded i cannot seem to get this fixed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update your selenium-driver (it works for me) :

```
gem 'selenium-webdriver', "~> 2.34.0"
```

Comment: That did not work for me. I put that line in my gemfile, ran a bundle. That didnt work so i ran bundle update and i am still getting the same error message.